# show error when certain charcters inputted in java

Tags: java

how do i go about editing my code, so when any letters of the alphabet is entered or numbers from 3 to infinity as well as any other characters entered an error will show up on screen. this is what i have got so far:

```
        System.out.println("Please Choose: 1: Enter 2: Upload"); 
        command = input.nextLine(); 

    {
        if(command.equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("Error, Please Try Again.");

     }
```

how would i go about to define certain characters to not show up in the if statement above

Comment: For example, you could define these characters in a `HashSet`, then see if your `Set` contains the `command` character. That's the best way I could think of to do it cleanly.

Comment: Since you want only 1 or 2, just check if it is 1 or 2. You do not have to check for all the other characters...

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath What about negative numbers ;)

Comment: @MuratK. He is asking for only 2 numbers. Please check the code above.There are only 2 options he is expecting so checking those 2 options would be ideal instead of writing all the regex logic or checking other characters. It has nothing to do with the negative numbers.

Comment: @MuratK. He is just checking the "a" part. Have you checked the code? He has no indication in the code that checks 1 or 2. As the answer states, he can check 1 or 2 as he is asking for user to input 1 or 2. Nothing else is required. Writing simple codes are better most of the time.

Comment: @MuratK. Stackoverflow is a platform that people advises the best coding approach. Because he wants to check it that way does not mean it is the best way. We are here to recommend the best approach. There are multiple solutions to the problem, and the offered solution works and provides an answer to question in a simplistic manner.

Comment: @MuratK. I will not  respond to your comments anymore as they are really not constructive. You should consider everything when you are making a calculation. The if else statement is going to execute way faster than running a HasSet since there are only 2 variables. In his case, the best answer, the fastest way to proceed would be the if else statement. I would agree with the HashSet if it was a large set of data but it is only 2 values that does not require a HashSet. I would advise you to read more articles like this one : https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/kiss.html

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with simple if...else if ..else

```
if(command.equals("1")){
    // do "Enter" work
}
else if(command.equals("2")){
    //do "Upload" work
}else{
    //print error
}
```

Otherwise, if you have a more complex pattern you can use [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern to match the wanted result.

A typical invocation sequence would be:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<Your Regex Pattern goes here>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(command);
boolean b = m.matches();
if(b){
    //command matches the pattern
    //code goes here
}
```

See [Pattern java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more.